# Plugins problem in Gradle with Multi-project

Tags: java, gradle

I looked at the sample and followed it.
(Gradle version is 6.8.3)

https://docs.gradle.org/6.8.3/samples/sample_building_java_applications_multi_project.html

I just only append plugin 'io.spring.dependency-management' at demo.java-common-conventions.gradle file.

```
plugins {
    id 'java' 
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.7.RELEASE' // append
}
```

Then run the **gradle build**,
The following error occurred.

> - What went wrong: Invalid plugin request [id: 'io.spring.dependency-management', version: '1.0.7.RELEASE']. Plugin requests
>   from precompiled scripts must not include a version number. Please
>   remove the version from th e offending request and make sure the
>   module containing the requested plugin
>   'io.spring.dependency-management' is an implementation dependency

So I tried removing version.
Then, the following error occurred.

> Plugin with id 'io.spring.dependency-management' not found.

I've tried adding a dependencies as well, but I still got a not found error.

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' 
}

repositories {
    jcenter() 
}

dependencies {
    implementation "io.spring.gradle:dependency-management-plugin:1.0.7.RELEASE"

    constraints {
        implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-text:1.9' 
    }

    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.6.2' 

    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine' 
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform() 
}
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The solution is in the error:

> What went wrong: Invalid plugin request [id: 'io.spring.dependency-management', version: '1.0.7.RELEASE']. Plugin requests from precompiled scripts must not include a version number. Please remove the version from the offending request and **make sure the module containing the requested plugin 'io.spring.dependency-management' is an implementation dependency**

So `demo.java-common-conventions.gradle` will look like:

```
plugins {
    id 'java' 
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management'
}
```

Now you must add the dependency for Spring Dependency Management plugin in `buildSrc/build.gradle`:

```
// buildSrc/build.gradle

dependencies {
    implementation "io.spring.gradle:dependency-management-plugin:1.0.7.RELEASE"
}
```